# using in_array with smarty section loop

Tags: php, smarty

Here is my smarty template file:

```
{section loop=$Author name=Author}
<option value="{$Author[Author].Id}" 
{if $Author[Author].Id|in_array:$ListAths.AuthorId})}
selected
{/if}
>
{$Author[Author].AuthorName}</option>
{/section}
```

My PHP structure for both variables (Author and ListAths) Looks something like this with substituting the correct variable for sql and smarty commands:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare(/*command here*/);
$stmt->execute($array);
$result = $stmt->fetchall();
$smarty->assign('ListAths', $result);
$stmt2 = $connect->prepare(/*command here*/);
$stmt2->execute($array);
$result2 = $stmt2->fetchall();
$smarty->assign('Author', $result2);
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /mydirectory/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(171) : eval()'d code on line 71
```

`$ListAths.AuthorId` is not recognized as an array! How can I fix the problem?

it works this way:

```
{section loop=$Author name=Author}
<option value="{$Author[Author].Id}" 
{section loop=$ListAths name=ListAths}
{if $Author[Author].Id == $ListAths[ListAths].AuthorId}
selected
{/if}
{/section}
>
{$Author[Author].AuthorName}</option>
{/section}
```

But I still would like to do it using the in_array

Comment: `is not recognized as an array` Error description tells you that it is **NULL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cannot comment to ask which smarty version you use... assuming smarty 3 you can use any PHP function (and also objects) in your smarty templates...

```
{section loop=$Author name=Author}
<option value="{$Author[Author].Id}" 
{if in_array($Author[Author].Id, $ListAths.AuthorId)}
selected
{/if}
>
{$Author[Author].AuthorName}</option>
{/section}
```

Comment: Problem is that `$ListAths.AuthorId` is NULL

Comment: ok, so there may be a problem with assigning the variables `$smarty->assign($itisauthororlistathshere, $result);` looks strange if using `$ListAths` in template... is the variable `$ListAths` assigned somewhere?

Comment: $itisauthororlistathshere can equal ListAths or Author.

Comment: @bohrsty I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: i'm a bit confused how you get your `$result` and `$result2` to assign to the template... do you only give a short version of `mysqli::stmt_init()`, `$stmt->prepare()`, `$stmt->execute()`, `$stmt->fetch()` in your question? as far as i know `mysqli_stmt` does not have a `fetchall()` method, so the results may be NULL...